# Epi-convergence and normal cones

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

I have a series of lower semi continuous, eventually level bounded and proper functions 
$  f^\nu(p)$ that epi-converges to $f(p)$.

In this context, it is known from e.g., [7.33, Variational analyis, Rockafellar and Wets] that the sequence of global minimizers $f^\nu(p)$ converge to a global minimizaer of $f(p)$.

The question is the following.
Is it also true that a sequence of **local** minimizers of $f^\nu(p)$ converge to a **local** minimizer of $f(p)$?

Additionally, if I have a set sequence $C^\nu$ that converges to $C$ (in the Painlevé-Kuratowski sense), under which circunstances the normal cones converge $N_{C^\nu} \to N_C$?

By the way, neither the functions nor the sets are convex.

Thank you!

Comment: Set $f^\nu(x) = x^2 + \nu \sin(x)$ for $\nu\to0$. It  has many local minimizers that vanish for $\nu\to0$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
Maybe I did not understand properly your comment... it is true that the local minimizers vanish but also the sequence of local minimizers converge to 0, which is the global minimizer of the original function (and hence, also a stationary solution).